# Targeting a specific widget title with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

On my wordpress powered website I have widget title boxes if you have a look you will see I have a one titled 'british lions' in the left sidebar on the right hand side of the website.

This is a category widget and will only show posts from that category. I would like to change the title box from green to red to match the 'british lions' style.

I will then add more of these widgets but they will be pulling from different categories and will also have their own color style. You will see what i mean on the main content on the front page aviva is yellow super rugby is blue etc etc but i want this for the widgets aswell.

How do i target the specific widget boxes with css to change the background. I have tried with firebug but it seems to change all the widget title boxes and not that specific one i am after.

http://www.rugbyclubhouse.net

Hopefully someone can help and i am making sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.
Let us take the 'British Lions' tab here for instance.

```
#feacpost_featuredcategorypostswidget-2 h3 {
    background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Take this css and put it inside your own stylesheet.

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry =) if it helps, I share your feelings ... it happens to me all the time that I'm just a little too late ... so I give you a solidarity +1 ;-)

Comment: Thanks @MartinTurjak I appreciate. +1 from me too for being such a nice guy ;).

Answer (score 3):

you can access it by its id `#feacpost_featuredcategorypostswidget-2`.

so you could add something like

```
#feacpost_featuredcategorypostswidget-2 h3 {
    background-color: #b22023;
}
```

to your CSS.

Comment: you can also do something similar for the tag buttins by trying something like `#wellthemes_recent_tags_widget-2 a[href="http://rugbyclubhouse.net/tag/lions-2/"]{background-color: #b22023;}`

Comment: as you are new to stackoverflow ... to accept an answer that was helpful you can select the tick at the side =)