# Wordpress CSS, selecting elements for all widgets of a certain type?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, wordpress-theming

I'm totally new to CSS and I'm trying to modify a Wordpress theme. I have searched for my question and the closest I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358365/targeting-a-specific-widget-title-with-css), but I don't understand what to do using that example.

Basically I want to hide the title element 'custom-sidebar-title-wrapper' of all widgets of a specific type, that being 'widget_goodlayers-1-1-banner-widget'.

Here is the class hierarchy I copied from element inspector.

```
<div class="custom-sidebar widget_goodlayers-1-1-banner-widget" id="goodlayers-1-1-banner-widget-31">
    <div class="custom-sidebar-title-wrapper">_</div>
    <div class="under-banner-title">_</div>
    <div class="banner-widget1-1"">_</div>
</div>
```

The way that I have been trying to solve the problem is this

```
div.custom-sidebar widget_goodlayers-1-1-banner-widget custom-sidebar-title-wrapper {
display: none;
}
```

But it doesn't work, probably because I am doing something wrong or putting things in the wrong order, please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting a space between two classes on the same element and not prefixing your classes with `.`:

Change: `div.custom-sidebar widget_goodlayers-1-1-banner-widget ...`

To: `div.custom-sidebar.widget_goodlayers-1-1-banner-widget ...`

And change: `custom-sidebar-title-wrapper`

To: `.custom-sidebar-title-wrapper`

```css
div.custom-sidebar.widget_goodlayers-1-1-banner-widget .custom-sidebar-title-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

This selects the element with class "custom-sidebar-title-wrapper" *descendant* of any `div` element with classes "custom-sidebar" and "widget_goodlayers-1-1-banner-widget".

You can refer to the [Selectors documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) for in-depth info about each selector type.

Comment: Thank you! This will help me so much because I'm having to do a sidebar banner navigation menu using about 40 individual banner widgets and widget logic because ad banner systems get blocked. Until now they couldn't have any titles and that meant scrolling to the end of the jpeg url to even know what they were hahaha